# confirmation before exit dialog

Tags: javascript, html, api, exit, confirm

In most pages, if your doing an action, (like editing, creating), and when I attempt to exit,  it mostly prompts me if I really want to exit. The dialog gives me two options: leave or cancel and continue. How do you accomplish this in JavaScript? Do I have to use a meta element? <strike>And please don't mention `beforeunload`, unless it's the true and only way to accomplish this.</strike>

Comment: check: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

Comment: @rags Not on confirm boxes alone, confirm boxes when you attempt to exit the page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not mention `onbeforeunload`? It's the built in way to do so, and I don't see a problem using it.

```
function myConfirmation() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to quit?';
}

window.onbeforeunload = myConfirmation;
```

Comment: This produces the browser default leave or stay dialog. If you want something fancier, you can have that function call up a jQuery or Fancybox dialog for example, and return `true` or `false` based on what happens in that fancier dialog.

Comment: @chenasraf I had no idea the browser produced a default dialog! +1

Comment: @chenasraf There is a time limit, I have to wait 5 min. before accepting any answer.

Answer (score 0):

what I use is:

```
onClick="return confirm('Sure you want to exit..?')"
```

Answer (score -5):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
      if(confirm('are you sure to exit?')) 
           return true; 
      else 
           return false; 
};
```

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for the pretty print.

Comment: Alex, this results in duplicate dialog.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, not only does this no longer work (due to confirm being blocked in onbeforeunload) this causes the default dialog to show with "true" or "false". Just have your onbeforeunload return the text you wish to show the user and the browser will sort it out from there.